# Return async task which is using another async function

Tags: c#, task, .net-4.5, async-await

I am trying to return Task paremeter in a function that uses async function and got in trouble.

Here is my code:

```
 private async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
 {
   return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
   {
       await func();

       some code..

       return 123;
   });

 }
```

I get the error: "cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type"..

Is there any way to do call the async functnion from the new task?

Comment: Can't you move `await func();` out of the `StartNew` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to show how you could correct your initial syntax to resolve the compiler error and still keep the same signature of the `GetIntAsync` method:

```
private async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(42);
        return 123;
    }).Unwrap();
}
```

Here is the same code with a bit more explicit typing, so you could better understand what's going on:

```
private async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    Func<Task<int>> lambda = async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(42);
        return 123;
    };

    Task<Task<int>> outerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(lambda);

    Task<int> innerTask = outerTask.Unwrap();

    return await innerTask;
}
```

Indeed, this approach is unnecessary complex and you have a redundant `await` here. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20759583/1768303) by @user2720372 suggests the **right** way of creating a task using `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thank you so much, both explanations and code was very useful!
However, I still have a problem. “await” doesn't wait for the completion of call. Here is my code:
      Task<int> response = GetIntAsync();
      int a = await response;
Thanks ahead;

Comment: @user1662033, I'm not sure what you mean under *`await` doesn't wait for the completion of the call*. If you need a real blocking wait rather than an asynchronous continuation, you use `task.Wait()` instead of `await task`, although it's usually a sign of the bad code workflow design. Here's a [test console app](http://pastebin.com/TGHKDHTm) that works. Note `testTask.Wait()` inside `Main()`, it's there because `Main` is the app's entry point which cannot be `async`. Do read Stephen's [Async Intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post, it's very helpful.

Comment: Also, I agree with @StephenCleary's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20764625/1768303) that you most likely don't need to create a separate task with `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` inside `GetIntAsync`. Normally, you'd do it if you wanted to perform some lengthy CPU-bound work (`some code..`) inside `GetIntAsync` (to avoid blocking the UI when `GetIntAsync` itself is called on the main UI thread). That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 11):

You almost certainly do not want to call `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run`. Instead, just use `async` and `await`:

```
private async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
   await func();

   some code..

   return 123;
}
```

For more information, see my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return `Task<int>` from your method you can't declare it as `async` because you don't await anything in it (you only await in the inner `Task`):

```
private Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return 123;
        });
}
```

or if you do await, the return type should be `Task<Task<int>>`:

```
private async Task<Task<int>> MyMethod()
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);

   return Task.Run(async () =>
   {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 123;
   });
}
```

Comment: I think you should also explan why did you change `Task.Factory.StartNew()` to `Task.Run()`.

Comment: check this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx